# Can you make the protected field inherited from the super class a subclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I know it is not possible to override overide fields, but I want to ensure that the fields in the subclass extending the abstract class implement the needed interfaces.

I have an abstract class like this:

```java
public abstract class Foo<T extends Commandable> {
    protected T context;

    public Foo(T context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

and I want to specify that type T implements the interface `Commandable`

The interface looks like this:

```java
public interface BasicCommandable extends Commandable
```

So my subclass looks like this:

```java
public class Bar<BasicCommandable> extends Foo {
    
    public Bar(BasicCommandable context) {
        super(config, context);
    }
```

I may just be misinterpreting how to use generics. I have tried using Class<? extends T> but that only leads to the exception `BasicCommandable cannot be converted to class`. Is this possible or am I just missing something?

Comment: It would be `public class Bar extends Foo<BasicCommandable>`

Comment: @Kayaman, thank you! That problem may or may not have taken an hour from my life haha.